# Measure upload speed in swift

Tags: ios, swift, upload

I have my own server in which I want to upload my file to in Swift. I also want to measure the upload speed. Below I create an empty 1 mb Data object and upload it.

```
        let urlString = "https://myserver/upload.php"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            return
        }

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let emptyData = createEmptyData(of: 1048576)

        let json = ["file" : emptyData]
        urlRequest.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(json)

        let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
        let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

        session.dataTask(with: urlRequest).resume()
```

How do I measure the upload speed? Thanks

Comment: speed is determined by distance or size / time. so see how long it takes to upload 1Mb

Comment: @Scriptable In which delegate method of URLSessionDelegate should I calculate the upload speed?

Comment: You dont need a delegate method. session.dataTask has a completion handler. You can use that.

Comment: @Scriptable I see, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
      let urlString = "https://myserver/upload.php"
      guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
         return
      }

     var timer: Timer?
     var uploadTask: URLSessionUploadTask!

     var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10)
     urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
     urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

     let emptyData = Data.init(capacity: 102454)

     let json = ["file" : emptyData]
     urlRequest.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(json)

     let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
     let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
     uploadTask = session.uploadTask(with: urlRequest, from: emptyData) { (data, response, error) in
        if let err = error {
            //There's an error
        }
        else if let response = response {
            //check for response status
        }

        //Stop the timer here
        timer?.invalidate()
      }

    uploadTask.resume()
    calculateSpeed()
}


func calculateSpeed() {
    var previousBytesSent: Int64 = 0
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { (_) in
        let bytesSent = uploadTask.countOfBytesSent
        let speed =  abs(bytesSent-previousBytesSent)
        //Here you get the speed in Bytes/sec
        previousBytesSent = bytesSent
    })
}
```

Comment: Here, you are using an uploadTask instead of a dataTask. Therefore you are supplying the empty data in both the JSON body and the task itself. Is that right?

Comment: You can use dataTask too. Properties like countOfBytesSent, countOfBytesReceived etc are available in DataTask also as both of them inherits from URLSessionTask.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use Core Foundation's absolute time method at the beginning of the method and subtract the value from the absolute time at the end of the method once you're done uploading the file.

```
func uploadData(){
        let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        var uploadTask: URLSessionUploadTask!

//Code for uploading file

        uploadTask = session.uploadTask(with: urlRequest, from: emptyData) { (data, response, error) in
        if let err = error {
            //There's an error
        }
        else if let response = response {
            //check for response status
        }

       //Once upload is complete
       let totalUploadTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start
      }





}
```